# infile dlm='@@', but truncated email address

Tags: file-io, sas, dlm

I am trying to use:

```
infile dlm='@@' dsd missover;
```

to copy a SAS code to a new location, but it truncated email address (there is an email address e.g. abc@xyz.com in the SAS code), and only the username 'ABC' show up in the new code, and the '@xyz.com' part was truncated.

So i excluded the infile option

```
dlm='@@'
```

re-run the code, and the email address was read correctly, however some regular lines are missing.

Just wonder if some infile options I can try to read all the lines correctly, also read the email address correctly too.

thanks!

an example:

```
*91,87,95 abc@xyz.com test hudpiwaHUOV0 
 97,,92% bmno[aej0i34hmbtgkoersw934bnrtui9sdobn vnbud9rw0aq598vnfjipa 
 njuio9rpep0snhtui9es000 
 from="mjerrt_thpian@wedoo.com" 
 fjsui123,1,1 0 ;

 data a;
 infile "/.../email.xlsx" 
   missover dsd lrecl=32767 firstobs=1;* dlm='@';     * delimiter = '@@';
   informat all $char50. ;
  input all $ ;
  pk=_n_;
 run;
```

Comment: Can you show example data lines you are trying to read and the actual input statement you are using.  Note that setting DLM='@@' is the same as setting DLM='@' as the value of the DLM option is the list of individual characters that will each be considered a delimiter. So repeating one of the characters multiple times does nothing.

Comment: just gave an email, please check it out and thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot read a binary XLSX file as if it was a plain text file.

Comment: Values that contain the delimiter need to be enclosed in quotes.  So if you have data like: `field1@filed2@joe@host.com@filed4` you need to generate the text file with quotes like this:  `field1@filed2@"joe@host.com"@filed4` instead.  Your example appears to be using space as the delimiter.

Comment: You comment under the answer make is sound like you don't want to split the lines into words at all.  So don't.  Just use formatted input.  Use `$CHAR` informat if you want to preserve leading spaces on the line.  `infile 'xxx.txt' truncover; input line $char5000.;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your data is using space as the delimiter.

Let's convert your example text into a file so we have something to test against.

```
filename txt temp;
options parmcards=txt;
parmcards4;
*91,87,95 abc@xyz.com test hudpiwaHUOV0 
 97,,92% bmno[aej0i34hmbtgkoersw934bnrtui9sdobn vnbud9rw0aq598vnfjipa 
 njuio9rpep0snhtui9es000 
 from="mjerrt_thpian@wedoo.com" 
 fjsui123,1,1 0 ;
;;;;
```

Now we can read the file and parse it into the individual "words".

```
data parse ;
  infile txt dlm=' ' length=llen column=ccol ;
  lineno+1;
  do wordno=1 by 1 until(ccol>llen);
    length word $200 ;
    input word @ ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    lineno    wordno    word

  1       1         1      *91,87,95
  2       1         2      abc@xyz.com
  3       1         3      test
  4       1         4      hudpiwaHUOV0
  5       2         1      97,,92%
  6       2         2      bmno[aej0i34hmbtgkoersw934bnrtui9sdobn
  7       2         3      vnbud9rw0aq598vnfjipa
  8       3         1      njuio9rpep0snhtui9es000
  9       4         1      from="mjerrt_thpian@wedoo.com"
 10       5         1      fjsui123,1,1
 11       5         2      0
 12       5         3      ;
```

If you add the DSD option to the INFILE statement you will get more words since adjacent (or leading) spaces will indicate an empty word.

Comment: thanks Tom, that is good, but, if multiple blanks is existing, that will truncate the blanks. e.g. abcde flag='TU ' ; in the output will be abcde flag='TU ' ;   Also, if there a empty row between the first and second row, I want to keep the empty row. Anyway, I just want to keep the new file the same as the old one. thanks again!

Comment: Why are you trying to split it into pieces if you want to leave it the same?  Do you mean you want to read each line as one long string value?

Comment: Add the `truncover` option to the `infile` statement to stop it from skipping the blank lines. Add the DSD option if you want to keep track of where multiple spaces appear next to each other.

Comment: it works, but if the space within a quotation marks e.g. x='abc de    fg', it will delete some spaces only 1 space left. wonder if we can fix that, thanks!

Comment: If you are using the DSD option and you have something that looks like a quoted string it will remove the quotes, not the spaces.  You could try adding the `~` modifiier after the variable name in the input statement to prevent it from removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
infile 'email.xlsx' dlm='00'x;
```

if you really need no delimiter.